# How do I autowire dependencies into Spring @Configuration instances?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration, annotations

I need to inject an object into my No XML Spring @Configuration object as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "web.client")
public class WebApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebApplicationConfiguration.class);

@Inject
private MonitoringExceptionResolver resolver;  // always null

@Override
public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {
    log.debug("configuring exception resolvers");
    super.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(exceptionResolvers);
    exceptionResolvers.add(new DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver());
    exceptionResolvers.add(new AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver());
    exceptionResolvers.add(new ResponseStatusExceptionResolver());
    exceptionResolvers.add(resolver);  // passing null ref here
}

}
```

Where MonitoringExceptionResolver is defined as follows:

```
@Service
public class MonitoringExceptionResolver implements HandlerExceptionResolver {

private final Counters counters;

@Inject
public MonitoringExceptionResolver(Counters counters) {
    super();
    this.counters = counters;
}

public ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) {
    Counter counter = counters.getCounterFor(ex.getClass());
    if(counter != null) {
        counter.increment();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

However, I get NPE later in the execution chain because the "resolver" field above is null, even if I use @Autowired.

Other classes are being successfully wired in elsewhere using component scanning. Why is it always null in the above? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using @Autowired instead of @Inject?

Comment: Where do you declare the object you want to autowire or inject? Because before you can use those annotations, the bean should be declared in the context.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd yes, I already mentioned this in the above.

Comment: @JonathanCruz I thought @ Configuration was a declaration to include the object in the context. Do I also need to annotate the @ Configuration class with a stereotype annotation like @ Service?

Comment: @Ricardo Gladwell Im not sure but i would try to add it to you applicationContext.xml or webcontext. @ Configuration should work also but i think it has been introduced recently so it might not always work properly. I believe its from spring 3.0. And if you use @ service you should be able to autowire it.

Comment: @JonathanCruz I don't have an applicationContext.xml, that's why I'm using @ Configuration. I added @ Service stereotype but still get the same problem, the @ Inject members are still null when configureHandlerExceptionResolvers() is called.

Comment: Do you have any xml? I dont know really how it would work without applicationContext.xml, sorry cant help you more. Check here , maybe that helps you. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations

Comment: I tried replicating the behavior you are seeing but I am not seeing any issues at all, the resolver is getting correctly wired in for me. Can you confirm your `MonitoringExceptionResolver` belongs to the the package in `@ComponentScan` - `web.client`

Comment: @JonathanCruz thanks, i'll check that link out

Comment: @BijuKunjummen double checked and those classes are definitely in the @ ComponentScan base package. What version of Spring are you using? I'm on 3.1.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

@Inject and @Autowired should work very similar in Spring.
Make sure that *BeanPostProcessor in use is aware of MonitoringExceptionResolver: mark it as @Component and make is subject of some @ComponentScan or make a @Bean factory method is some @Configuration class in use.

Comment: as from the above code fragment, @ComponentScan is enabled, and I did mention that objects are otherwise being wired successfully.